# Django Celery Issue

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery for an asynchronous task in my project. But when I try to run the worker, it gives me the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Not able to figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: Could you share a command you use to run the worker, please?

Comment: I used celery -A myproject worker -l info

Comment: What does your Celery configuration in your project look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Django settings before initializing them. For example you might be reading something from Django settings in your worker code.

Or this might be caused by wrong configuration in your celery script.

Need more information to give better answer.